# Problems getting the position of a click in a custom PyGame grid

Tags: python, pygame

So, basically what I am trying to do is a customizable version of Tic-Tac-Toe. I have a function that can perfectly display a grid, with a specific amount of rows and columns, but now I am trying to make a function that would get the position in that grid. This is the code I am using:

```
def getGridPos(rows, cols, display, pos):
    x, y = pos
    width, height = display.get_size()
    xPos, yPos = (0, 0)
    for yCount in range(rows):
        if y <= height / rows * yCount and y >= height / rows * (yCount+1):
            xPos = yCount
    for xCount in range(rows):
        if x <= width / cols * xCount and x >= x <= width / cols * (xCount+1):
            yPos = xCount

    return (xPos, yPos)
```

And in case I am just being derpy when printing it out:

```
print("You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % getGridPos(3, 3, display, event.pos))
```

So, basically what is happening here is that when I press a cell in the first and second columns, it is gonna return (0, 2), but on the third column, it returns (0, 0). I don't know what is going on here, but I am going to try with some other sizes and then I will update this.

### **UPDATE**

So, I tried it out with some more configurations and this is my conclusion:

- When pressed in the first 7 columns in a 10x10 layout, it is gonna return (0, 2)
- When pressed in the last 7 columns in a 10x10 layout, it is gonna return (0, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Such code does not need `for` loops or `if`conditionals at all - 
simple arithmetic can give you an straight answer:

```
from __future__ import division

def getGridPos(rows, cols, display, pos):
    width, height = display.get_size()
    x, y = pos 
    return (pos[0] // (width / cols), pos[1] // (height/rows))
```

(I just get the division semantics from Python 3 with the `from __future__` line so there is no need to worry about converting values to float prior to dividing - which is possible what is actually wrong with your original code, besides it being a lot more complex than it should)

Comment: Thanks so much! By the way, could you give me a link to the documentation about those division semantics?